# Stuck at SharePoint2016 config Wizard

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, administration, sql

I already followed the tutorial and instructions but still cannot create database from SharePoint Config wizard.

Even I used SharePoint 2016 Management Shell, but still :
"Cannot connect to database master at SQL server at ####. The database might not exist, or the current user does not have permission to connect to it"

What I think is SharePoint cannot connect to SQL Server, I use SQL server 2012.

Because when I click create it loading about 30 sec, then show up that warning.

How to know that SP2016 could connect to SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Check as following to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Make sure that the Database server is up and running. From the
   SharePoint Server, try to ping the SQL Server Virtual IP
   to make sure that it’s reachable.
2. The default SQL Server Port is 1433, so make sure that you can
   telnet the SQL Server Virtual IP on SQL Server Port.

> telnet "the SQL Server IP" 1433

3. Check if the SQL Server Service is running on your Database Server,
   open SQL Server Configuration Wizard,check the **SQL Server Service** and **SQL Agent** and make sure both are started and worked properly.
4. Check the permissions for the Setup account which you are using to
   run the wizard or PowerShell. Make sure the setup account is granted
   with “**DB_Creator**” and “**Security_Admin**” Server Roles.
5. Verify “TCP/IP” protocol is enabled under the Network Configuration section of SQL Server Configuration Manager.
6. Check if there are any firewalls blocking the SQL Server, you could disable firewall or set FireWall State to “Allow”, then create two Inbound Connections Rules as the following:

> One inbound TCP rule with ports: 1433,2383,2382.
> One inbound UPD rule with port: 1434.

For more information, please refer to:

https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/cannot-connect-to-database-master-at-sql-server-at-servername-the-database-might-not-exist-or-the-current-user-does-not-have-permission-to-connect/

Comment: I try to ping telnet, the answer is "Connecting To the...Could not open connection to the host, on port SQL Server IP 1433: Connect failed". and what should i do now?

Comment: at the manager server there`s a lot ERROR log SQLSERVERAGENT : OpenSQLServerInstanceRegKey:GetRegKeyAccessMask failed (reason: 2).

Comment: Go to the SQL Server Configuration Manager->SQL Server Network Configuration->Protocols, check that named pipes and tcp/ip are enabled, in addition, SQLServer Express edition does not support SQL Server Agent, which will occur the error you posted.

Comment: Still can`t do..
I try to test the connection using udl file.
use username and pass admin on it, the result : [dbnetlib] ConnectionOpen (connect()). sql server does not exist or access denied.  But when I use sa account, it could connect and read master and other db.

Comment: I Reinstall SP2016 and SQL server, and now I use SQL server 2014.
no mysqlagent error and now when i try to create database the log is : Unknown SQL Exception 53 occurred. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible...... (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: For this issue, please refer to this official article:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15